# How to detect an entity with same name as player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map where you can morph into entities and fight other players with that, and for this map I need a way to teleport an entity that has the same name as a player to said player.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear: The asker wants to check whether another entity has the same `CustomName` as a player's name. That involves string comparison, which I haven't seen asked about here yet.